# fatal: http://myserverip/home/git/example.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, clone

I followed [this example](http://blog.commonthread.com/2008/4/14/setting-up-a-git-server/comments/10715#comment-10715) to set up a git repository on my server.  It worked, and I successfully `push`ed my code to it.

But now, how do I pull or clone?

Using [the docs](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), I tried

> git clone http://REMOTE_SERVER/home/git/example.git

.. But for me, I'm getting:

> fatal:  http://myserverip/home/git/example.git/info/refs not found:  did you run git update-server-info on the server?

I ran git-update-server info, but nothing changed

## Edit:

Ah, hold on.  I changed it to `git clone ssh://REMOTE_SERVER/home/git/example.git` and I'm getting something.. it wants my user/pass, but how do I make the server public then not requiring login?

Comment: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#apachehttp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#apachehttp

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serve it via (simple) http, you need to run git-update-server-info in the repository on the server after each update.

You can automate that by making the post-update hook run it (usually the default post-update hook just needs to be enabled (make the script executable)).

With a little more configuration of your webserver [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) can give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, wait, I got it, [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#setting-up-a-public-repository) explains how to do it using [git-daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html):

### SERVER:

- Start up `git-daemon &`
- `touch git-daemon-export-ok`

### CLIENT:

<kbd>git clone **git**://myserverip/home/git/example.git</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In all my git talks I speak of DAV as the "Loch Ness monster" -- I've heard it exists but have not actually seen it :-)

And as of late last year, with git-http-backend, you no longer need this "monster".  Please upgrade past 1.6.6 and treat yourself to a much better experience.  No more DAV... just plain apache with a smart little CGI talking to real git...